# Android Talkback keeps saying Webview

Tags: android, accessibility, android-webview

I have set content descriptions for the webview and I have overridden dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent but talk back keeps saying webview when the webview first loads.  Is there anyway to turn that off.

Thanks.

Comment: did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: No. Android provided Accessibility for WebViews in Api 14 and improved it in Api 16

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: Facing same issue...any solutions

Comment: I still haven't found a solution for this.

Comment: Has anyone found solution for this issue?

Comment: Anyone found a solution for this?